# javascript : prevent backspace on select that is dropped down

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have a select element with a few options in it.
When I drop the select to pick an option and I press the backspace key, regardless of how I trap the backspace key, my code has no effect whatsoever and I go back to the previous page.

```
 <select>
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="pear">pear</option>
  <option value="orange">orange</option>
  <option value="orzo">orzo</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(function(){

            // Firefox
            $("select").keypress(function(e){ return (e.which != 8)});

            // IE
            $(document).keydown(function(){
                return (typeof window.event != 'undefined' &&
                            event.keyCode == 8 &&
                            event.srcElement.type == 'select-one');
            });

            });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m1h1mcqu/1/

What can I do to prevent the 'back' browser when the user press the backspace key while a select element is dropped down ?

Thank you

Comment: What versions of IE are you trying to support?

Comment: tough spot but think about it, who hits the backspace when selecting an option? I've been there, don't drive yourself crazy, the only sure fire way I've found to prevent, is to give a text box focus, but is it really worth it?

Comment: you are probably right .. maybe I should not worry about it .. I just find it strange that the behavior is different when the select is dropped down vs when it is not ..

Comment: I've been trying in Safari; it doesn't support keypress with the `select` element.